# Calculating $\sin^2(2\pi/7)\cdot(2/1.05)$

Tags: trigonometry

I'm trying to calculate

$$\sin^2(2\pi/7) \cdot (2/1.05)$$

But not getting the right answer ($1.164$)

Can someone break it down step by step. I'm doing

$\sin(2\pi/7)^2\cdot(2/1.05) = 1.37$??

Comment: Are you using a calculator or not?

Comment: Yes using a calculator

Comment: Are you in radians?

Comment: I haven't checked, but I would guess you might have set your calculator to calculate in degrees, instead of radians.

Comment: Yes i am...jdfk

Comment: I've tried both radians and degrees not getting 1.164

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are calculating $$\sin\Bigl(\left(\frac{2\pi}{7}\right)^2\Bigr)\cdot\frac{2}{1.05}\approx1.37$$
This is NOT the same as $$\sin^2\Bigl(\frac{2\pi}{7}\Bigr)\cdot\frac{2}{1.05}\approx1.164$$
I.e. $\sin^2(x)=(\sin(x))^2\neq\sin(x^2)$

Comment: How do you calculate the second one then?

Comment: First, calculate $\sin(\frac{2\pi}{7})$. Then, square that whole thing. You're squaring the angle first.

Comment: Ah, thank you very much. I'll mark you right answer

Comment: Glad I could help. If there's any more confusion, the last line of the post should clear it pretty well.